# Вызов функции (action) из Form(ModelForm)

Tags: python, django

Занимаюсь изучением Django разрабатывая свой проект.
В случае необходимости поменять атрибут (name) своей модели я использую такую конструкцию:

template:

```
    <div id="change_name" class="change_form_ozp">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'rich:change_name' object.id %}" id="text_zamechanya">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Введите новое имя:
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="change_name_input" name="change_name" required maxlength="20" size="25">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Изменить">
        </form>
    </div>
```

views:

```
def change_name(request, id):
    res_object = Res.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       name = request.POST['change_name']
       res_object.name = str(name)
       res_object.save()
    return redirect('rich:res_detail', id=id)
```

В данной конструкции все работает прекрасно. Вопрос в том чтобы для реализации данной задачи использовать формы наследуемые от ModelForm для проведения их валидации стандартными средствами Django. Если такой вариант возможен буду благодарен за пояснения. Либо пните к нужной странице документации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Получается что сформированную джангой форму мы можем поместить в теги  прямо в шаблоне. При этом дублирования не будет.`

```
<form id="rich_add" method="post" action="{% url  'rich:add_rich' object.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="rich_add_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ rich_form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Только теперь имеется проблема валидации. Пока разбираюсь, когда упрусь выложу вопрос.